# synchronized block/method without wait() and notify() notifyAll() methods

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, thread-safety, deadlock

I recently came across a code where, synchronized keyword was being used in the method declaration, but there were no wait(), notify(), notifyAll() methods were used inside the method definition.

My question here is, as far as I know synchronized blocks or methods use wait(), notify(), notifyAll() methods for inter-thread communication when handling multiple thread interaction.So is it possible to have a synchronized block or method without having wait(), notify() or notifyAll() methods in it.

Thanks

Comment: yes, it is possible, the block will be executed by just one thread at a time

Comment: 'synchronized keyword was being used in the method declaration' - this way such method will not be executed simulatanously by different threads, no need for wait/notify, data modified in such method is safe against any race conditions - as long as it is modified safely

Comment: Is there any possibility here, that if a thread execution stops by some reason and all the threads which are in waiting state, waits for indefinite time without getting notified?

Comment: Yes. If a thread has an infinite loop or blocks forever inside a synchronized method, all the other threads waiting on the lock will wait forever. But why would you do that? A thread execution doesn't "stop by some reason".

Comment: No, I was trying to say that if an exception is thrown(without being handled it properly) while performing some operations or some database operation which is slow, by that time would the waiting threads be in waiting state without getting notified

Comment: If an exception is thrown and isn't caught in the synchronized block, then the thread leaves the synchronized block, so another thread can enter it.

Comment: Perhaps we should clarify the terminology first. A thread is *blocked* when it tries to enter a synchronized block, but another threads holds the lock. If the owning thread leaves the synchronized block, regardless of whether normally or by an exception, it will release the lock and one of the blocked threads may enter the synchronized block. A thread is *waiting* if it called `wait` or a similar method settling on `wait`. If no-one ever calls `notify`, the `wait` may last forever. “may” because in some rare situations, a waiting thread may return without a cause (known as “*spurious wakeup*”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mandatory that `wait(), notify() and notifyAll()` should always be called from within a synchronized block. But it does not mean that synchronized blocks should always have one of these methods.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a `synchronized` block (or `synchronized` method) is to prevent threads from interfering with each other when they access shared data.  The purpose of `wait()`, `notify()`, and `notifyAll()` is coordinate the actions of two or more threads.

But, just because two or more threads need access to the same shared data, that does not always mean that they need to coordinate with each other to achieve a shared goal.  Sometimes it's enough that they just keep out of each other's way. That's what `synchronized` does—it keeps threads out of each other's way.

Also, note: Just because you don't *see* explicit wait/notify calls, that doesn't mean they aren't there. Sometimes threads coordinate by the use of higher-level synchronization objects (e.g., `BlockingQueue`) that might use wait/notify (or [something equivalent to wait/notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)) in their implementation.